# Splitting a string seems not to work

Tags: c#, regex, string, split

I have problems with reading a file (textasset) line by line and getting the results!

Here is the file I am trying to read:

```
AUTHOR
COMMENT 
INFO      1  X   ARG  0001       0.581   2.180   1.470
INFO      2  X   ARG  0001       1.400   0.974   1.724
INFO      3  X   ARG  0001       2.553   0.934   0.751
INFO      4  X   ARG  0001       3.650   0.494   1.053
INFO      5  X   ARG  0001       1.188   3.073   1.532
INFO      6  X   ARG  0001       2.312   1.415  -0.466
INFO      7  X   ARG  0001      -0.232   2.249   2.180
END
```

Here is the code I am using:

```
//read file
string[] line = file.text.Split("\n"[0]);

for(int i = 0 ; i < line.Length ; i++)
{
    if(line[i].Contains("INFO"))
    {
        //To replace all spaces with single underscore "_" (it works fine)
        string l = Regex.Replace(line[i]," {2,}","_");

       //In this Debug.Log i get correct results
       //For example "INFO_1_X_ARG_0001_0.581_2.180_1.470"
       Debug.Log(l);
       string[] subline =  Regex.Split(l,"_");
       //Only for first "INFO" line i get correct results (INFO,1,X,ARG,0001,0.581,2.180,1.470)
       //For all other "INFO" lines i get incomplete results (first,fourth and fifth element are not put into substrings
       //like they are dissapeard!
       foreach(string s in subline){Debug.Log(s);}
    }
}
```

Explanation:

I first split text into lines (works fine),then i read only lines that contain `INFO`

I loop all lines that contain `INFO` and replace all spaces with underscore `_` (this works fine)

I split lines that contain `INFO` into substrings based on underscore `_`

When I print out the lines only first line with `INFO` seems to have all substrings
every next line is not splitted correctly (first part `INFO` is omitted as well as third string)

It seems very unreliable. Is this the way to go with these things? Any help is appreciated! This should be simple, what i am doing wrong?

EDIT:

Something is wrong with this code (it should be simple, but it does not work)

Here is the updated code (i just made a `List<string> list = new List<string>()` and copied all substrings. I use unity3D so that list contents show in the inspector. I was shocked when i so all properly extracted substrings but simple

```
foreach(string s in list)
 Debug.Log(s);
```

was indeed missing some values. so I was trying different things and this code:

```
for(int x = 0; x < list.Count ; x++)
{
  Debug.Log("List: " + x.ToString() + " " + list[x].ToString());
}
```

shows contents of the list properly, but this code (note that i just removed `x.ToString()`) is missing some elements in the list. It does not want to read them!

```
for(int x = 0; x < list.Count ; x++)
  Debug.Log("List: " + list[x].ToString());
```

So i am not sure what is going on here?!

Comment: regex implementation differ across languages..you should specify the language you are using

Comment: i am using c# and regex should be fine

Comment: What encoding are you reading the file with? Open the file in a hex editor and ensure it is in the same encoding you are reading.

Answer (score 0):

Try `string.split("\t"[0]")` You have probable tabulators between columns.

Answer (score 0):

There are some problems

1>The contains method you are using is case sensitive i.e INFO != info

You should use

```
line[i].ToLower().Contains("info")
```

2>Is the text always separated by space.it may also be separated by tabs.you are better off with

```
Regex.Replace(line[i]," {2,}|\t+","_");
//this would replace 1 to many tabs or 2 or more space
```

Comment: Thanks for replying, i tried what you suggested and it is not the case, both cases give the same result :( , i updated the question with new findings check it out

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try something like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < line.Length; i++)
{
    if (line[i].Contains("INFO"))
    {
        string l = Regex.Replace(line[i], @"\p{Zs}{2,}|\t+", "_");

        string[] sublines = l.Split('_');

        // If you want to see the debug....
        sublines.ForEach(s => Debug.Log(s));
    }
}
```

The `\p{Zs}` will match all Unicode separator/space characters (e.g. space, non-breaking spaces, etc.). The following reference may be of some help to you: [Character Classes in Regular Expressions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/20bw873z.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

The following seems to be working for me:

```
using (var fs = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open))
using (var reader = new StreamReader(fs))
{
    string line;
    while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        if (line.StartsWith("INFO"))
        {
            line = Regex.Replace(line, "[ ]+", "_");
            var subline = line.Split('_');

            foreach (var str in subline)
            {
                Console.Write("{0} ",str);
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
        }

    }

}
```